# How to create a slice from a list that contains all entries equal to 5?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, slice

```
x=r'C:\Users\beladiy\Desktop\python\DAT210x-master\Module2\Datasets\Servo.data'
df=pd.read_csv(x,names=['motor', 'screw', 'pgain', 'vgain', 'class'],header=None)
```

How can I create a slice from `vgain` that contains values equal to `5`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
x=r'C:\Users\beladiy\Desktop\python\DAT210x-master\Module2\Datasets\Servo.data'

df=pd.read_csv(x,names=['motor', 'screw', 'pgain', 'vgain', 'class'],header=None)

df=df[df.vgain==5]
```